# Algorithm for optimal spacing in intervals

Tags: algorithms

Is there an algorithm to optimally space points within multiple intervals? Optimal in this case means maximizing the smallest distance between any two points so that each pair of points has at least distance X. For example, in the intervals (1,3) and (5,7) you can space out three points with a distance of at least 2 (at 1,5, and 7). But you can't space out three points with a distance of at least 3. Is there an easy way to do this with a program?

Comment: Note that $5$ and $7$ are not members of the interval $(5, 7)$ (that's an open interval, not closed). Are you assuming the input is closed intervals?

Comment: @6005 yes the input is closed intervals. Thank you for pointing out the mistake!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  A simple approach is to use binary search on the separation distance $d$: given $d$, it is easy test whether there is a way to space out $k$ points so that all are at least $d$ apart (I'll let you figure out how; if you can do it for one interval, you should be be able to do it for multiple intervals).  Then use binary search on $d$.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer! I was thinking about binary search, but wasn't sure how to implement it. As for testing whether you can space out the points with a certain separation distance d, I can see how it would be done with one interval (dividing the size of the interval by the separation distance. However, I don't see how it would be done with multiple intervals because the space/distance in between each pair of interval must also be taken into account.

Comment: @casualproger Hint: use a greedy algorithm.

Comment: Oh I see.  I think you just place points at the leftmost available space (keeping in mind the separation distance). You keep placing points until you run out of points (distance d works) or you run out of space (distance d does not work). Is that right?

Comment: @casualproger If you're not sure, I suggest you try to prove whether it works.

Comment: This might not be a rigorous proof, but I do believe this method works because moving a point to the right (or removing a point altogether) will never increase the total number of points you can fit in the intervals.

Comment: @casualproger, nice job!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It is much appreciated.